# Facebook Login as supplement to existing login?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, user-accounts, authentication

I am developing a PHP/MySQL e-commerce site with some social aspects, and am looking to integrate it with Facebook. I already have a native user registration/session handling system. I have managed to include the iframe "Social Plugins" such as a "Like" button. But I really would like to offer users the option of registering with the site via Facebook over the native registration process.

I understand the idea of getting an access token via the OAuth protocol, and eventually getting a user ID. My concerns are two-fold:

1. Is this method secure? This is an e-commerce site, but I am not storing any credit cards or any other sensitive data. I can't think of how this could be exploited, but I am only one head!
2. I understand how to retrieve the initial token and get the user ID during the registration process. But how do I recognize a return (session) user? Do I have to implement the Javascript SDK for that (something I want to avoid)? Or, do I handle the sessions just like they already are handled natively, but replace a normal user ID in the session cookie with a Facebook user ID when appropriate?

I apologize if the answers are obvious. I have scoured Google and the Facebook documentation, but half the links I find are to deprecated FBConnect wiki articles, and the new docs are helpful, but sparse on the examples. I have no idea what is still supported, what is new, and how to do this!

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use SDK? SDK is a convenient wrapper for all that "low level" oath stuff you would need to worry about yourself otherwise. Just slap `fb:login-button` button on your site and then use one line of code to get logged user id (either in js or server side).

Comment: I guess I am just confused as to the integration of client side javascript with server side PHP. My site's native login mechanism uses PHP session and is already built. I am confused on the steps necessary to take the login authentication from javascript and establish a secure PHP session with it. I know javascript sets a cookie - do I have to rely on that and replace my entire existing session setup? My brain has a hard time wrapping around the idea of involving a third party during the login process!

Comment: You would normally need JS and PHP facebook api's for that. JS api would be used to display facebook login dialogs, while PHP can be used to get logged in user id. You don't need to worry about session, in PHP api you would first initialize it (by providing your app info), and then simply say something like `$api->getLoggedUserId()` (not familiar with exact php api syntax). Then you can store returned id in a session yourself if you want. Another option would be using FB connect only to make your existing registration easier for fb users (similar to Digg) (*sorry run out of space*)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Yes Oauth is very secure. Many many applications rely on it and there are no known ways to exploit it.
2. One way you could do this is store the Facebook id's of users so when they come back you can see that their id already exists in your records and know it is a returning user. Their session may be different (expired since last visit for example) so you don't want to store their access token; but their Facebook user id is always be the same.

How I basically integrated Facebook registration/login on my site is I added a facebook_id column in my users table and a "Register with Facebook" button. If the user clicks, authenticates with Facebook and I get back a session and the user is new, I redirect to the registration page, prefill as many fields as I can with data from Facebook (like their name), and add the Facebook id as a hidden input field. Therefore when they register, their facebook_id will be filled in the database. This is the same registration page as the standard one, so the only difference with a non-Facebook user is that the facebook_id field will be empty. If you want, you can also not require a password for Facebook users.

For the user to log in, the user would just click a "Login with Facebook" button and authenticate with Facebook. Once Facebook gives me the session, I log the user in as whatever user has the facebook_id as the one in Facebook's session. Since you are worried about security, I'll note that this session cannot be forged as it is signed with the application secret key that only you and Facebook know. If you use Facebook's SDK (which you should) you do not have to worry about the signing and signature verification. The fact that you can read coherent information from the session means that Facebook's SDK has verified it.

[This Facebook page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web) is a great guide on integrating registration with Facebook.

Comment: Thanks, that was great. I guess I just needed a high level overview of how the login mechanism worked with existing session handling. I think I have a handle on it - now to actually attempt it!

Comment: Thanks good explanation for exciting database structure